# Sequelize associations: set[Models] adds new models instead of associating existing ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and I'm trying to create associations between two different tables, where `x.belongsTo(y)` and `y.hasMany(x)`. After having done `x.setY(yInstance)` and `y.getXs()` it seems only new rows have been added to x and no associations to my already created instances have been created.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird"),
    Sequelize = require("sequelize");

var sequelize = new Sequelize("Test", "postgres", "password", {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "postgres",
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    }
});
var Schedule = sequelize.define("Schedule", {
    website: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});
var SiteConfig = sequelize.define("SiteConfig", {
    systemType: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});
var Selector = sequelize.define("Selector", {
    type: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});
Selector.belongsTo(SiteConfig);
SiteConfig.hasMany(Selector);

var testSchedule = {
    website: "google.com"
};
var testSiteConfig = {
    systemType: "one"
};
var testSelectors = [
    {type: "foo", content: "foo"},
    {type: "foo", content: "bar"}
];



Promise.all([
    Schedule.sync({force: true}),
    SiteConfig.sync({force: true}),
    Selector.sync({force: true})
]).then(function () {
    return Promise.all([
        Schedule.create(testSchedule),
        SiteConfig.create(testSiteConfig),
        Selector.bulkCreate(testSelectors)
    ]);
}).spread(function (schedule, siteConfig, selectors) {
    return Promise.map(selectors, function (selector) {
        return selector.setSiteConfig(siteConfig);
    }).then(function (array) {
        return siteConfig.getSelectors();
    }).each(function (selector) {
        // This is where I expect "foo" and "bar" but instead get null
        console.log("Selector content:", selector.get("content"));
    });
});
```

I'd expect this code to add a `SiteConfigId` column to my `Selectors` so that my `siteConfig.getSelectors()` would return my testSelectors. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE]

It turns out what I had earlier was wrong. The method `setSiteConfig()` is not what you want to use. I checked the db and it looks like Sequelize created two new records instead of associating the existing foo/bar selectors:

```
test=# select * from "Selectors";
 id | type | content |         createdAt          |         updatedAt          | SiteConfigId 
----+------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------
  1 | foo  | foo     | 2015-04-05 20:38:55.282-07 | 2015-04-05 20:38:55.282-07 |             
  2 | foo  | bar     | 2015-04-05 20:38:55.282-07 | 2015-04-05 20:38:55.282-07 |             
  3 |      |         | 2015-04-05 20:38:55.282-07 | 2015-04-05 20:38:55.311-07 |            1
  4 |      |         | 2015-04-05 20:38:55.282-07 | 2015-04-05 20:38:55.31-07  |            1
```

So what is different? You can't use `setSiteConfig` on the child rows, instead you call `addSelectors` on siteConfig and pass in the selectors you want to associate. See updated code below.

Changed `Promise` variable to `BPromise` because node has a native `Promise` module now which would cause a conflict. Also I believe Sequelize has bluebird built-in so you can also just use `Sequelize.Promise`.

Removed the nested promise in your `spread` call because there is no need for it.

Side note: `Promise.all` returns a single result array so I don't think you should be using `.spread()`.

```
var BPromise = require("bluebird");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

var sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'root', 'password', {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "postgres",
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

var Schedule = sequelize.define("Schedule", {
  website: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

var SiteConfig = sequelize.define("SiteConfig", {
  systemType: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

var Selector = sequelize.define("Selector", {
  type: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  content: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

Selector.belongsTo(SiteConfig);
SiteConfig.hasMany(Selector);

var testSchedule = {
  website: "google.com"
};
var testSiteConfig = {
  systemType: "one"
};
var testSelectors = [
  {type: "foo", content: "foo"},
  {type: "foo", content: "bar"}
];

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
.then(function(result) {
  return BPromise.all([
    Schedule.create(testSchedule),
    SiteConfig.create(testSiteConfig),
    Selector.bulkCreate(testSelectors, { returning: true })
  ]);
})
.then(function(result) {
  var siteConfig = result[1];
  var selectors = result[2];

return siteConfig.addSelectors(selectors);
})
.then(function (result) {
  return this.siteConfig.getSelectors();
})
.each(function(result) {
  console.log('boomshakalaka:', result.get());
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I should also add that I use sequelize.sync() instead of syncing each individual model.

Comment: Thanks, your code worked just as expected! I realized though, that the primary problem with my code was that I was using `bulkCreate` for the testSelectors instead of `create`, which returned the inserted rows without ID's. From the docs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#working-in-bulk-creating-updating-and-destroying-multiple-rows-at-once

It seems your code could have the same problem (although it doesn't in practice), can you help me show why it works or maybe edit your answer to iterate over testSelectors (instead of bulkCreate) and I'll happily mark it as accepted :)